# setcookie function and phpinfo in php not working but in localhost work

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I tried to write a code that set a cookie and check if `isset` this cookie show massage "cookie create" else show "cookie not create" but it not work this code in localhost work correctly.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php setcookie("a","abcdef",time()+3600); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
phpinfo(); 

if(isset($_COOKIE['a']))
{
echo $_COOKIE["a"];
}
else
{
echo "no cookie";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - setcookie(); not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316870/php-setcookie-not-working)

Comment: no this question dont solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

As answered by this other question on Stack Overflow, [PHP - setcookie(); not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316870/php-setcookie-not-working), your PHP application is emitting HTML output before attempting to set the cookie:

```
<html>  <------- oh no!
...
<?php setcookie("a","abcdef",time()+3600); ?>
```

At this point, PHP has already finished sending the **HTTP headers** (not to be confused with the HTML `<head>` tag) and the cookie cannot be set (which must be done as part of the HTTP headers).

Set the cookie first and you should be fine:

```
<?php setcookie("a","abcdef",time()+3600); ?>
<html>
...
```

Be certain you are calling `setcookie()` before any other (non-HTTP-header) output.